# nivo slider overflow issue

Tags: css, html

I am using nivoslider for my webpage. The images look overflow one by one until the page loading fully. Here is the css i'm using. I have tried `overflow:hidden` property. But it didn't get corrected. How can i correct that?

CSS :

```
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; overflow:hidden;
    left:0px;
}
/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:500px;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:60;
    display:none;
}
/* The slices in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    height:100%;
}
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    /*opacity:0.8;  Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
    width:100%;
    z-index:89;
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:99;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="slider">                 
    <img src="uploads/images/6431-45-york-st-kitchen-b.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />                
    <img src="uploads/images/9931-45-york-st-front-a.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />                  
    <img src="uploads/images/8931-45-york-st-bed-1a.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" /> 
    <img src="uploads/images/3931-45-york-st-bath-a.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />
    <img src="uploads/images/4031-45-york-st-study-a.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />   
    <img src="uploads/images/7531-45-york-st-kitchen-a.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />    
    <img src="uploads/images/1931-45-york-st-living-b.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />   
    <img src="uploads/images/5531-45-york-st-foyer-a.jpg" width="315" height="250" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe a look at the HTML will be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a height for `#slider` and add the `overflow:hidden` to it

This will perfectly fix it

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly in slower connection and there is no way to handle this.

But, what you can do is to call the nivo slider function after the page has loaded fully. just use the window.onLoad property and call the nivo function inside it.

Like following

```
<script>
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
        /* call to your nivo function */
    }
</script>
```